# Match all character before numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to do operations with the numbers in a string, but the operation depends on the char before that number, so I need to get **the char** before any number in a string. **Note** that the char before a number could be another number.

So far I've done `/(.)[0-9]/g`, but this is not matching the case where there's a number before another number. For example:

```
positions: 0123456789012
string:    a a4 bb4 c44c
```

matches:

1. `a4` [2-3]
2. `b4` [5-6]
3. `c4` [9-10]

**It doesn't match `44` [10-11]**

How can I match this one too?

Comment: Maybe you need `.(?=[0-9])`?

Comment: With this regex I get the char before the number, but then I don't know how I can use the number itself, that is needed for the operation. How would you do it with that approach?

Comment: You can capture it: `.(?=([0-9]))`

Comment: Actually, if you show the code, and provide exact output you need, you would get relevant help much quicker. Right now, you say *all the chars*, but you are using `.` in the pattern, while it should be `.*?`

Comment: You are right, my description can be misleading. I've edited it. Anyway your second comment is just what I needed :) I didn't know that you can capture something that is out of the actual match using the lookahead!

Comment: You can just use `/(?=(.[0-9]))/g`. The answer below with `/(.)(?=([0-9]))/g` looks rather ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a much simpler regex:

```
/(?=(.[0-9]))./g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bL0hS0/1)

This regex matches any char except newline and carriage return (`.`) that is a any char other than LF/CR followed with a digit.

This pattern does not match an empty string and does not require additional code to check if we matched an empty string (like `if (m.index === re.lastIndex) re.lastIndex++;` in anubhava's answer, that is redundant even in that solution, and this way you can avoid concatenating captured group values).

The actual value is stored in Capture group 1 that is inside a positive lookahead to allow getting overlapped matches. Since the captures are lost if we use `str.match(re)`, we have to rely on `RegExp#exec` inside a loop.

```js
var re = /(?=(.[0-9]))./g; 
var str = 'a a4 bb4 c44c';
var res = [];
while((m=re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: That is just what I need. The answer by @anubhava is also correct and I can use it to solve my problem. I accept your's because you were faster helping and your answer is better developed. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex with 2 captured groups:

```
/(.)(?=([0-9]))/g
```

and concatenate captured group #1 and #2 for your results.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wZ1oP0/2)

```js
var re = /(.)(?=([0-9]))/g; 
var str = 'a a4 bb4 c44c';
var m;
var results = [];
     
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex)
        re.lastIndex++;
    results.push(m[1] + m[2]);
}

console.log(results);
//=> ["a4", "b4", "c4", "44"]
```